# Munin で MySQL のグラフが表示されない

Tags: mysql, monitoring, munin

munin-nodeを設置しました。linux2(aws ec2 Kernel 5.10)
mysqlをモニタリングするために以下のリンクを参考してec2インスタンスに設置しました。

[Munin（ mysql 監視）](https://rin-ka.net/munin-mysql/)

テストサーバーではできましたが、自分が現在使っているmysqlの環境では失敗しました。
mysqlはテストサーバーと現在使っているサーバーは同じバージョン(MYSQL5.7.34)ですが設置方法間違ってます。

- test server - installing mysql from yum, rpm
- my own mysql server - Installing mysql from Source

セッティングは問題は同じ方法でしました。
（ps.テストサーバーと現在のサーバーのmysqlの経路が違うのでmysqladminの経路を現在のサーバーのファイルに追加しました。ー＞/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node）

テストサーバー(/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node)

```ini
[mysql*]
env.mysqlopts -u root --password=[password]
```

現在のサーバ(/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node)

```ini
[mysql*]
env.mysqladmin /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
env.mysqlopts -u root --password=[password]
```

結果) my own mysql server

```
$ sudo munin-run mysql_queries
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
delete.value 5
insert.value 5
replace.value 0
select.value 65
update.value 4
cache_hits.value 0
```

テストサーバーでは問題なかったですが、現在のサーバーはmysqlのGraphが見えないので。。

この問題をどうすれば解決できますか？

Comment: munin 自体はどのようにインストールしましたか？/ munin-run の結果を見る限り、値の取得は出来ているようにも見えるので、グラフが見えない = HTML ファイルの出力で何らかの問題があるのかもしれません。`/var/log/munin/` 以下のログファイルもチェックしてみるとよいかも。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。おかげで問題を解決しました。LOGを見て解決できました！innoDBの経路とか問題発生した問題が記録されていたので。

Comment: お役に立てたようで何よりです。せっかくなので解決までにご自身で調べた事などをぜひ回答として投稿してみてください。

Comment: @cubick はい。内容を整理して、回答として投稿するよていです。もう一度ありがとうございます！